# Powering Computers

Tags: electrical-power

How much electricity is required to power twenty average computers on a LAN?

Comment: How much wood would a wood chuck chuck if a wood chuck could chuck wood?

Comment: There is no way to figure this without knowing what the computers are..... If you give us the computer I guess its possible to tell you.

Comment: Define what you consider to be "average" then we can talk. Are your figures supposed to include the LAN itself?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/123009/how-can-i-calculate-power-consumption-of-my-pc-in-watt [Why Estimate When You Can Measure](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/why-estimate-when-you-can-measure.html)

Answer (score 2):

Well, an average *office* computer burns between 120-250 watts of energy at any given time, the LCD 80-150 watts. Multiply by 20 and you get 4Kw to 8Kw. Given the average 120v 20a circuit and you'll really need 3 circuits to cover all of that plus incidentals. 240v allows more overhead, you could probably get away with 2 circuits.

Comment: 80W for an LCD seems... excessive. The Samsung 22" I use at work has a "typical" power draw of 40W - do you have a power meter you can test with?

Comment: @Andrew Hey, it's a WAG.

Answer (score 1):

Typical office computers use anywhere between 50 and 150 watts depending on specification when doing normal office type work. Don't forget to include the displays too.

Answer (score 1):

Many Asset management products will report on the hardware in use.  You can use a KilloWatt device that measures power consumption, to assess how much each different model eats in terms of power.

Then you can build profiles for each hardware configuration, and report on them, to then multiply by your calculated power usage.

Comment: Agree with actually measuring the power draw during use instead of guessing or relying on manufacturers claims.